# What to do with the test/docs/readme files after the downloaded python package is built?

Tags: python, macos, package, egg, file-management

Sorry about the nooby question, but, when I download and unzip a third-party python package, and then **python setup.py install** it thereby making an egg directory in site-packages, what do I do with the original unzipped directory in the Download folder? Should I sudo copy & paste all the test/docs/README files along with the rest of the corresponding site-packages files? I've typically deleted them but don't think that's a smart thing to do..

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can delete them without a problem. They are supposed to copy themselves over with the install.  You can also use `pip` or `easy_install` to make things easier on yourself.

Comment: `easy_install` is definitely a godsend in that regard. It's just troubling when the package is not there and I have to manually build it from zip file.

Comment: true, but if it is using setuptools/distutils, it's basically the equivalent of using pip or easy_install.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that. But it does seem to not import the doc files from the zip file. Or perhaps those are automatically saved in another directory that's not site-packages. Hm..

Comment: okay, well the other possibility is that I'm wrong.  I *thought* they were equivalent, but it really depends on the code.  I'd just open up setup.py and see what it says...everything that's actually copied should be documented in there.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to use the installed Python package, then you don't need the downloaded directory at all.  You can delete it if you like.  If you want to use it for its docs, then you can keep it, or move it somewhere else.  There's no connection between the installed package and the original unzipped directory you installed from, so you are free to do what you like with it.